# Strategies to reduce the whois query burden

Tags: php, javascript, whois

I have been working on operations with strings in a recent 100 level CompSci course.
I got the very "original" idea that I might write up a simple domain name generator/checker.

So I did a little homework and discovered that the various whois servers understandably limit the number of queries allowed.

So, I decided to first check for a DNS boolean. If no records are found I then check a MySQL database to make sure the same query hasn't been sent recently.  If it hasn't I fire off a whois query with PHP using fsockopen.  So, I was just getting ready to finish up my little script and upload it from my development server to my production server and I found some sites suggesting that various whois servers limit the queries to only 1,000.

My question:

Am I approaching this appropriately?
The simple math suggests that only 10 users each checking out 10 searches each search providing only 10 results (10**3) might result in exceeding the limit and a temporary ban.

Are there any methods of doing bulk queries to the whois server?

Are other sites using some form of client-side javascript query or server-side proxy?
I found another similar question here at stackoverflow suggesting that *NIX systems have access to a terminal command that has no limits.  Other questions I have found deal with parsing the data - which is not a concern of mine.

I understand that this is a vague question.  I do not want to inappropriately burden the whois servers. I do not expect, nor want, a ready-made code solution.  A basic discussion of alternative programmatic strategies to go about this would make me a very satisfied friend :)  Anyone have a keyword or two with which I can continue my research?

Comment: I have been doing some more research since I posted this question.  I am a little fuzzy on how ajax and jquery function together.  Would a solution like the one in the following link process the request client-side? http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if your question was indeed answered!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whois unix command appears to be *less* limited (https://superuser.com/questions/452751/what-are-the-limits-of-whois-command-on-unix). It might be easiest to do what I assume `whois` is doing under the covers and open a tcp connection to whois.internic.net on port 43.

```
<?php

$fp = fsockopen("whois.internic.net", 43);
fwrite($fp, "hello.com\n");

$response = "";
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $response .= fread($fp, 8192);
}

fclose($fp);
echo $response;

?>
```

If that's what you're already doing, then that's probably your best bet. I'm guessing a 1,000 query limit likely refers to the use of somebody's web service that does this for you (e.g. whois.com). I *think* you can make a lot more queries than that if you're doing what I showed above.

(I've made a lot of guesses and assumptions here.)

P.S. A lot of good info here: http://semmyfun.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-does-whois-work-dirty-guide.html

Comment: Any individual registrar is likely to throttle service to a repeat visitor, some as low as 100 queries per 24h; but `whois.internic.net` does not appear to have limits as far as I have been able to find out.  If all you need to know is whether a domain is available, then getting a referral or "not registered" is sufficient.

Comment: Wow! Thanks guys! Some very interesting information. It seems that the sites I found wailing about bans were likely the "second step" whois lookups and not the basic registered or not query.  Maybe I was making much adoo about nothing...

Comment: It does seem like my code is nearly the same as that above... I feel better already :)

Comment: tripleee:  Unfortunately, `whois.internic.net` is not sufficient for all domains.  The end of its output explicitly says:  "The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and Registrars."

Comment: No need to assume, read RFC3912 that fully describes the whois protocol: indeed you need to open a TCP socket on port 43 and senq your query on one line terminated by CR+LF to read back a blob of text.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you should use the registry whois server related to the TLD of the domain name you are interested in. See my extensive reply here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407030/211833

Answer (score 4):

Even though this has already been marked as answered (I've already typed this up for another post so I might as well reuse it) :-)

As has been said most whois authorities will throttle (or even block) your traffic if they deem that your making too many requests in a 24 hour period.

Instead you might want to consider logging in to the ftp site of any of the whois providers worldwide and downloading the various bits of the database, all of them make this public data available and it's exactly the same data that companies like maxmind use for their IP to geo lookup service, and it's the same data that sits behind all these 'whois' commands everyone automates.

I currently do this with one of my own servers, which connects using the following shell script (once every 24 hours) WARNING-- This will produce almost 4 gb of data so make sure you do this on a disk with plenty of space...:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f delegated-afrinic-latest
rm -f delegated-lacnic-latest
rm -f delegated-arin-latest
rm -f delegated-apnic-latest
rm -f delegated-ripencc-latest
rm -f ripe.db.inetnum
rm -f apnic.db.inetnum
rm -f ripe.db.inetnum.gz
rm -f apnic.db.inetnum.gz
wget ftp://ftp.afrinic.net/pub/stats/afrinic/delegated-afrinic-latest
wget ftp://ftp.lacnic.net/pub/stats/lacnic/delegated-lacnic-latest
wget ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/arin/delegated-arin-latest
wget ftp://ftp.apnic.net/pub/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest
wget ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/delegated-ripencc-latest
wget ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/dbase/split/ripe.db.inetnum.gz
ftp -n -v ftp.apnic.net <<END
user anonymous anonymous@anonymous.org
binary
passive
get /apnic/whois-data/APNIC/split/apnic.db.inetnum.gz apnic.db.inetnum.gz
bye
END
gunzip ripe.db.inetnum
gunzip apnic.db.inetnum
```

I then have a custom written program that parses the files out into a custom database structure which my servers then do their queries from.

Since all the servers mirror each others data, then you should be able to get a full data set from one server, but if not, then it wouldn't take much to modify the above shell script to download the data from the other servers, all of them respond to 'ftp.????' and have the same universal folder structure.

I can't help you with the parser however as that contains proprietary code, but the file format (esp if you get the split files) is identical to what you see in a typical whois output so it's very easy to work with.

There is a parser on google-code (That's where I got the download script) called 'ip-country' (I think) it's designed to allow you to build your own whois database, the one I've built is slightly more complicated as it's combined with other data too (Hence why my parser is proprietary)

By downloading and processing your own data like that, you get around any limit imposed by the providers, and the upshot is that it's most likely way faster to query your own data store than keep firing off requests from your server to the query servers every time someone enters an IP address.

Comment: Notice that for some of the RIRs the bulk whois data is redacted due to privacy laws. Kinda funny, considering you can query their public APIs which are not redacted but are rate-limited.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the initial question (and it is at least the third time I see it on the site). You are dealing with RIRs databases, the OP is interested by domain names databases, even if they use the same tool (`whois`) these are two completely separate landscapes.

Comment: OK, I'm not going to get into this again.  Iv'e just re-read the initial question, and THE OP (WHO IS NOT YOU)  was quite clearly worried about the burden being placed on the servers to get whatever data he or she was after.  There was no mention of RIR's vs Domains or ANYTHING else.  My answer was an answer against the QUESTION, which was "HOW DO I GET PAST THE RESTRICTIONS ON HOW OFTEN I CAN CALL THE SERVER.", since my answer answered exactly that question, then like the other ones where you've gone around picking fights, YOU ARE WRONG here too.

Comment: Oh and I note, that I am NOT the only one who you gone around SO following for whois questions and then having a pop at them in the comments.  Iv'e found at least 3 other answered, just like me who answered the original question for what it was, and for what was actually being asked.

Comment: As I said in one of my other responses, if you felt the question was NOT ANSWERED, then the correct thing to do was to put an answer on, explaining why and what you felt the correct answer should be, that's how SO is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in whether domains are *registered*, rather than in the WHOIS details, you'd have a better time using DNS servers to do your checks rather than WHOIS.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am indeed running all queries through DNS first.  Unfortunately, it seems that many domain names are registered but do not have any nameserver info down the pike.  Because of this, only after I have done the DNS, I am then running it through internic.  Thanks tho :)

Comment: Wait... by check DNS do you mean a simple PHP checkdnsrr()?

Comment: No -- much like with WHOIS, you don't need to do a full DNS lookup. Simply querying the registrar nameservers (e.g, `*.gtld-servers.net` for `.com` domains) is sufficient. There doesn't appear to be a function to do this in the PHP standard library, though.

Comment: Hmmmm, no standard function, eh? Any direction or keywords I can research to lighten the DNS load as you've suggested?

Comment: Completely false. This is the contrary in fact. A domain name can be registered and hence existing without being delegated in the DNS, and this is completely legit. So, use `whois`.